# Justifying the differentiation property of the Fourier transform

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, fourier-transform

Let the Fourier transform of $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$, denoted by $\mathcal{F}f$, be defined as

$$ \mathcal{F}f(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ixy} f(x)\,dx.$$

An oft-quoted result is that if $f,f'\in L^1(\Bbb R)$, then

$$ \mathcal{F}(f')(y) = iy\mathcal{F}f(y).\tag{1}$$

This is justified with integration by parts:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ixy}f'(x)\,dx = \left.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-ixy}f(x)\right|_{-\infty}^{\infty} +iy\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ixy}f(x)\,dx.\tag{2}$$

The association between $(1)$ and $(2)$ is predicated on $f$ going to zero at $\pm\infty$, however there are plenty of differentiable $L^1$ functions which do not go to zero at infinity, e.g. take a compactly supported smooth function with support of width $\frac{1}{4}$, then center dilated copies of it at the integers with decreasing width away from zero. You could find a sequence of function values which never goes to zero in this case.

If $f$ were absolutely continuous, then it seems to me that this should be true since we would have (for any fixed $a$):

$$ f(x) = \int_a^x f'(y)\,dy + f(a).$$

Taking a limit as $x$ tends to infinity would give that

$$ f(\infty) = \int_a^{\infty} f'(y)\,dy + f(a).$$

Each quantity on the right hand side is well-defined and so $f(\infty)$ is  a constant, but the only constant it could be (to retain integrability) would be zero.

However without assuming absolute continuity this seems no-go since if $f$ was the Cantor function, $f' \equiv 0$ almost everywhere so the left hand size of $(2)$ is zero, the first term on the right hand side is zero since the Cantor function is compactly supported and the second term on the right hand side is nonzero since the Fourier transform is injective. (Unless of course I am mistaken about this.)

What exactly are the right conditions for the association between $(1)$ and $(2)$ to hold (or where has my logic broken down)?

Comment: I can't see your point...

$f,f'\in L^1$, so if $f'\in L^1$ the limit $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^{+\infty}f'(x)\,\mathrm d x$ exists, and since $f\in L^1$ this limit must be zero. Likewise $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=0$.

Comment: That is assuming absolute continuity which is fairly strong, as the Cantor function example shows. Just having $f, f'\in L^1$ is not enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your objection is indeed correct

Here is another demonstration:

$$\int_{\Bbb R} e^{-ixy}f'(x) dx = \int_{\Bbb R} \lim_{h\to 0} e^{-ixy}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} dx $$

$$= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h}\int_{\Bbb R}  e^{-ixy} (f(x+h)-f(x))dx $$

$$= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h}\int_{\Bbb R}  e^{-i(u-h)y}f(u)du - \hat{f}(y)$$

$$= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{e^{ihy}-1}{h} \hat{f}(y) = iy \hat{f}(y)$$

The key point is the interversion of the integral and limit, I let you choose your favorite theorem

Comment: A-ha! This makes it a lot clearer, though it makes me rather disappointed in how much this result is improperly stated in Fourier analysis texts. It's pretty clear why the example I gave fails since LDCT wouldn't work out. You seemingly need some form of uniform continuity (to make sure that $f(x+h)-f(x)$ can be bounded nicely) which I suppose is why absolute continuity works out. I was convinced I was wrong about this since so many people handwave the evaluation at $\pm\infty$ portion, even on here. I'm glad to know I was not incorrect in this.