# Does this term vanish after doing the Fourier transform of a function under a derivative even in a bounded domain?

Tags: derivatives, fourier-transform, spectral-theory, boundary-value-problem, integral-transforms

The Fourier transform of a function under a derivative is:

$$ \mathcal{F}\Bigg({df (t) \over dt}\Bigg) = 
{1\over \sqrt{2 \pi}}\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}{df (t) \over dt} e^{-iwt}dt \tag 1$$

Using integrations by parts we get:

$$ \mathcal{F}\Bigg({df (t)\over dt}\Bigg) = 
{1\over \sqrt{2 \pi}}\Bigg ( f(t)e^{-iwt} \Bigg |_{-\infty}^{\infty} + iw\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(t)} e^{-iwt}dt \Bigg ) \tag 2$$

$$ \mathcal{F}\Bigg({df (t)\over dt}\Bigg) = 
{f(t)e^{-iwt}\over \sqrt{2 \pi}} \Bigg |_{-\infty}^{\infty} + iwF(w) \tag 3$$

The thing that is actually confusing me is the first term on the right-hand side that we are assuming that it vanishes at the limits:

$$ {f(t)e^{-iwt}\over \sqrt{2 \pi}} \Bigg |_{-\infty}^{\infty} = 0 \tag 4 $$

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767551/justifying-the-differentiation-property-of-the-fourier-transform) post, the statement $(4)$ is valid if the function $f(t)$ is continuous and smooth. However, does this term vanish even if $t$ belongs to a bounded domain $[t_0, t_1]$? I am currently studying spectral methods for numerically solving PDE's. There, the domain is bounded, but it is assumed that this term still vanishes.

Comment: With a bounded domain, boundary terms will appear, because $f(t) \propto H(x-t_0) - H(t-t_1)$, where $H$ is the Heaviside function, whose Fourier transform is $\mathscr{F}[H(t)](w) = \pi\delta(w) + \frac{1}{iw}$, the first term being due to the bounded domain. Laplace transform is usually preferred to tackle functions with bounded support; indeed, one has $\mathscr{L}[f'(t)](s) = s\mathscr{L}(s) - f(0^-)$ for instance, where the last term comes from the boundedness of the integration domain.

Comment: I thought so. Thank you very much :D